# Multiple JPA Entities using same table

Tags: java, jpa

I have a database table that has a huge amount of columns. I want to access that table using different JPA Entities, so each entity should also represent a few columns of that table. Therefore I created two different @Entity classes which point to the same physical table using @Table(name ="personal") annotation. 
But this doesn't seem to work. As soos as I set the second Entity to the same table I get the following error whenever I try to work with those entities:

javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

So, this seems to be the wrong way.

What's the best way to deal with realy large tables if 90% of the columns are not of interrest ?
Is it possible to create several JPA Entity classes for the same database table ?

thanks for any help!
Thorsten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider to create multiple views of that table and bind these views to entities.

Comment: No in your database you create a view with only the columns you like and then you create an entity reflecting that view.